# Applying for a job by email and snail mail simultaneously - should I "warn" the HR that I duplicated my application?

Tags: resume, applications, email

If I apply for a job and send a CV by email (the expected way), but I believe that mailing paper resumes has some advantages as well - it's an actual piece of paper after all, someone can leave it on their desk and take a second look later on, or grab to skimread it on lunch etc....

So, the question is: if I send my application both by email and traditional mail, applying for the same position twice in a certain sense, should I specifically mention it in both applications?

Comment: Where are you located? You might be overestimating the value of the traditional application, even if there was a slight benefit, it's not worth the confusion. An email lets people deal with the application on their own terms (some will print it, other would rather not have to deal with paper). Do simply take care that your application also looks good when printed (include a PDF). Also, if you were explicitly asked to apply by email, sending a paper application is obnoxious and counter-productive.

Answer (score 3):

> if I send my application both by email and traditional mail, applying
>   for the same position twice in a certain sense, should I specifically
>   mention it in both applications?

Since most you likely expect your email to arrive first, just mention that you are following up with a paper version of your resume.

That way, the recipient will be on alert for the later arrival, and won't be surprised.